# How do I pass a payload to RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemChanged?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) of RecyclerView.Adapter, you can notify that an item has been changed and pass in an "optional payload object" that will then be merged and passed to [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)) to allow for more granular UI updates. However, when I actually try to call something like

```
notifyItemChanged(0, new Object())
```

Android Studio informs me that I have an extra argument - it wants me to use just `notifyItemChanged(0)`. And looking at the [source of RecyclerView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java) it indeed seems like no such method exists.

Is there actually a way to pass in a payload (do I have an old version of the lib or something), or is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have checked with an existing project and it works. See:

[image: notifyItemChanged with payload]

Its not about the sdk, i guess you are using an older version of the Library Containing the recyclerview and its adapter. Thats the Version I am using in my example.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```